# v-for over array and set input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I'm looping over a json in my template which works well.

Now I have an `array` which you can see down below and I want to loop over this array and want to input the first `number` into my first `b-form-input` `v-model` and `:value`, the second in the second b-form-input and so on.

So my indexChild is equal to the place of number which should be inputed. (`indexChild = 0` <-> `place of number in my array` = 0 **-> Input: 7011412**)

How I'm able to solve that?

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, indexChild) in json" :key="indexChild">
    <div class="mt-2">Input</div>
    <!-- v-for="item in array" :key="item" --> <!-- this doesn't work! -->
    <b-form-input v-model="???" :value="???" type="number"></b-form-input> 
  </div>
</template>
```

my array:

```
['7011412', '7012912', '7689012']
```

looks like this in console:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the v-model and value to json[indexChild]
Then your v-model is set to the value of the array at the given index

```html
<div v-for="(item, indexChild) in json" :key="indexChild">
   <div class="mt-2">Input</div>
   <!-- v-for="item in array" :key="item" --> <!-- this doesn't work! -->
   <b-form-input v-model='json[indexChild]' :value="json[indexChild]" type="number"></b-form-input> 
</div>
```